# Upload converted pdf from html page using python to aws s3 bucket

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way to convert a html page like **google.com** into pdf using python and upload to it directly s3 bucket without saving the file locally..It seems like it can be done using byte array but still can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You have two requirements in there... First, can you convert to a PDF without saving a file? Then, can you upload to S3 without saving a file? The answer to the second part is Yes, you can provide Bytes when creating an object (`PutObject`) in S3. So, you need to figure out if you can do the first part in-memory. (By the way, _why_ do you not wish to save locally?)

Comment: I am planning on to do it in django-q scheduling and it will run frequently, so might overload server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a headless browser, like [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to do this. Simply grabbing the html won't do and it will only work for no javascript html pages. Puppeteer requires a lot of resources, but you can deploy it as a lambda function. It can generate a PDF out of an HTML page. It should be possible to get a byte array out of it and upload it to S3.

Comment: i need to do it in django, pdf will be generated in hourly scheduling.